# Google Assistant API V2 userstorage

Tags: python, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm attempting to develop a Google Action with the Dialogflow v2 API

My function saves a value to userstorage as follows

```
def save_value(value):
res = {
  "fulfillmentText": "Set value to {}".format(int(value)),
  "payload": {
    "google": {
      "userStorage": str(value)
    }
  }
}
print ("Saved value")
response = jsonify(res)
return response
```

And I get the following back from testing in Dialogflow

```
{
  "fulfillmentText": "Set value to 36237269",
  "payload": {
    "google": {
      "userStorage": "36237269"
    }
  } 
}
```

This works for the duration of session, I am able to use this in later intents via

```
 value = request_json['originalRequest']['data']['user']['userStorage']
```

However, the data is only stored for one session - if I invoke my action again, there is nothing saved.

Is this the correct way of using userstorage? Has anyone successfully used it with Python?

Failed "response"

```
{
  "responseMetadata": {
    "status": {
      "code": 10,
      "message": "Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response",
      "details": [
        {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Value",
          "value": "{\"id\":\"816605a7-f7e0-4d37-a490-c84ff63fb7dd\",\"timestamp\":\"2018-11-08T17:18:49.422Z\",\"lang\":\"en-us\",\"result\":{},\"alternateResult\":{},\"status\":{\"code\":206,\"errorType\":\"partial_content\",\"errorDetails\":\"Webhook call failed. Error: 500 Internal Server Error\"},\"sessionId\":\"ABwppHHai3qsY2WPZWezmh9Q_bUF45aD51GbQ81sUDF7iSrRLA2m8KFgZ1ZYavnCv3fAckW1tcoJdydZTXQY5Nw\"}"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Working "response"

```
{
  "conversationToken": "[]",
  "finalResponse": {
    "richResponse": {
      "items": [
        {
          "simpleResponse": {
            "textToSpeech": "Text"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "responseMetadata": {
    "status": {
      "message": "Success (200)"
    },
    "queryMatchInfo": {
      "queryMatched": true,
      "intent": "047ad9d9-0180-47f9-88bd-e5ffc8936c08"
    }
  },
  "userStorage": "36237269"
}
```

Working "Request"

```
{
  "user": {
    "userId": "ABwppHE5H0FKrXKk8PjJyzZJ12OSMQcjxuT2NnfPAgLvai0UsfWEoYE8R_L8qLQdqY29sOnsZhQhE5G4XVVXiGs",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "lastSeen": "2018-11-08T17:18:16Z",
    "userStorage": "36237269"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "conversationId": "ABwppHE6BwK2zIBKxHA8hc9uBGumVgKbbNGHhRVFz7O6yrxxa1WJ_xtKNqhesj3EwNCVlestM-bF6tDWzZhqUXE",
    "type": "ACTIVE",
    "conversationToken": "[]"
  },
  "inputs": [
    {
      "intent": "actions.intent.TEXT",
      "rawInputs": [
        {
          "inputType": "KEYBOARD",
          "query": "when is the next bus"
        }
      ],
      "arguments": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "rawText": "when is the next bus",
          "textValue": "when is the next bus"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "surface": {
    "capabilities": [
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO"
      },
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
      },
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
      },
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
      }
    ]
  },
  "isInSandbox": true,
  "availableSurfaces": [
    {
      "capabilities": [
        {
          "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
        },
        {
          "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
        },
        {
          "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "requestType": "SIMULATOR"
}
```

Failed "request"

```
{
  "user": {
    "userId": "ABwppHE5H0FKrXKk8PjJyzZJ12OSMQcjxuT2NnfPAgLvai0UsfWEoYE8R_L8qLQdqY29sOnsZhQhE5G4XVVXiGs",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "lastSeen": "2018-11-08T17:18:41Z"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "conversationId": "ABwppHHai3qsY2WPZWezmh9Q_bUF45aD51GbQ81sUDF7iSrRLA2m8KFgZ1ZYavnCv3fAckW1tcoJdydZTXQY5Nw",
    "type": "ACTIVE",
    "conversationToken": "[]"
  },
  "inputs": [
    {
      "intent": "actions.intent.TEXT",
      "rawInputs": [
        {
          "inputType": "KEYBOARD",
          "query": "when is the next bus"
        }
      ],
      "arguments": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "rawText": "when is the next bus",
          "textValue": "when is the next bus"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "surface": {
    "capabilities": [
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
      },
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO"
      },
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
      },
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
      }
    ]
  },
  "isInSandbox": true,
  "availableSurfaces": [
    {
      "capabilities": [
        {
          "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
        },
        {
          "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
        },
        {
          "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "requestType": "SIMULATOR"
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include info about how you're testing this? If you are using the Action Simulator, can you include in your question the contents of the "request" tab from two different sessions?

Comment: Thank you, I've updated the comment - the failed response shows the following in logs as there is no userstorage after leaving the action request_json['originalDetectIntentRequest']['payload']['user']['userStorage'] KeyError: 'userStorage'

Comment: Can you also add the "request" tab?

Comment: Thank you, have done. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That is definitely peculiar. Have you tested from a device linked with the same account? How are you initializing the test each time?

Comment: Yes both from a physical device on alpha, and via "See how it works on Google Assistant".

Comment: You say "on alpha". Have you done this using just the development version?

Comment: Yes that’s right, I haven’t promoted the action to production...if that’s what you mean. Sorry am new to actions, if this is not what you’re referring to

Comment: That is more or less what I was referring to, but you can test both the "development" version as well as the "alpha" version if you have released something to alpha. I was checking which environment you were testing it with.